# How to write and read to Files using pipe in C

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

How can I read a file then transfer its contents to another file using pipes from register 1 to register 2 in C programming?

I understand how to do this when there is no file involved; meaning if the input is simply a string which the user inputs, then I create two processes using fork and use read and write. However, I have been struggling for 4 days straight trying to figure out how it works with file as an input...

Comment: Try this example https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-copy-file/

Comment: You've been thinking too hard, then.  When you read from a user, you're typically reading from the file stream `stdin`.  Instead of reading from `stdin`, you're going to need to read from the file stream returned by `fopen()` on the file you're supposed to read.  From there onwards, it's the same, give or take the name of the file stream pointer.  You'll probably be using `fgets()` — you were using `fgets(…, stdin)`, but now you'll use `fgets(…, fp)` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler quick question ! so if child process is reading form the pipe and then wants to put whaterever it read into a file would this be correct read (pipefd1[0], fp2, strlen (str)+1);

Comment: Using `strlen()` is almost invariably wrong with `read()` — and is here.  If `fp2` is a `FILE *`, then it is many times over wrong.  The `read()` function requires a pointer to an array of char and the size it can use; for example: `char buffer[4096]; int nbytes = read(pipefd1[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));` and then you can write up to `nbytes` of data to a file stream — `if (nbytes > 0 && fwrite(buffer, nbytes, 1, fp2) != nbytes) { …error handling… }`.  Note that `read()` does not return a null-terminated string and can be shorter than 4096; you need the count of the number of bytes it read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ohhhh that makes sense now ! thanks again!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so sorry to bother u again. So the instruction is that I have to read directly from the pipe and put whatever I read in the file. so... if I use a buffer, it defeats the purpose ! isn't it possible to directly put whatever it reads to the file without first putting it into a string/buffer and then move those from string/buffer to the file? I'm really stuck on this part!

Comment: You can look at the Linux [`splice()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) system call, but in standard POSIX what you are seeking to do is not possible.